# @Fontface working on Mac Chrome, but NOT on Windows Chrome?

Tags: html

Using @fontface, it's working absolutely fine with Chrome on Mac, but defaults to arial on Chrome with Windows.

Any ideas why and what I can do.
The code i have is as follows,

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Yearling yearlite';
src: url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.eot');
src: local('!'),
    url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.svg') format('svg');
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in this format, generated with [Font Squirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com/fontface).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ConsolasRegular';
    src: url('consolas/consolas-webfont.eot');
    src: url('consolas/consolas-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('consolas/consolas-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('consolas/consolas-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('consolas/consolas-webfont.svg#ConsolasRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You'll need to change the `font-family` and the paths, as well as the name after the hash for SVG.

Comment: However changing  url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.svg') format('svg');

Comment: to  url('../../fonts/YEARLITE.svg#Yearling yearlite') format('svg'); did work